# How to resize video for mobile mode in wordpress/php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, video, mobile

Hi so I added a video into the front-page.php code using the following code:

```
<div style="text-align: center" id="video"> 
<iframe width="867" height="488" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6c7Fx2PR9Dk" ></iframe></div>
```

(sorry for some reason the code editor is not working)
however when I try to change the width and height in the mobile mode using #video, it does not change. any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I added a class=container and changed the width to 100% and height to auto. This worked a  little better but now the height of the container needs to be bigger. I cannot seem to find where to add the code to edit it.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your code but I am sure it would be way easier to achieve this using CSS and media queries. Assuming your video player is configured to take 100% of the width of the container it sits in.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to use the following cass to make it full width

```
#video iframe {
width:100%!important
}
```

[Fitfids.js](http://fitvidsjs.com/) is really nice plugin to make the iframe, video embeds responsive. You may try to use that for your ultimate video responsive solution.